# How to execute one batch file occasionally?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Hey guys I have troubles writing batch file, could you help me with it? I want to write bat file that executes occasionally(every 2-3 hours for instance). I want to accomplish something like this:

```
cd D:\Repositories\myRepo
git checkout master
git pull
cd D:\Repositories\myRepo2
git checkout master
git pull
```

I know that in unix based OS there is command that there is `inotifywatch` command that can help me execute that file over period but I don't know what can do this in Windows. Could you help me? Also these six lines that I wrote doesn't seem to be working for some reason? Is there any chance that I execute them one after another because I am not sure if they are waiting one another right now..

Comment: watch for errormessages. Surprisingly they can help finding Errors. "Does not work" is not helpful at all. What do you expect from your Code and how is the actual Output different?

Comment: for regular executing, there are "scheduled tasks" (either via GUI or via commandline. See `schtasks /create /?` for a quick overview what can be done.

Comment: @Stephan by doesn't work I mean it opens CMD and immediately closes it. It did nothing else..

Comment: while testing, don't start with a doubleclick. Open a `cmd` window and start it manually. So the window keeps open and you can have a look to what's going on (or not going on).

Comment: Thanks for the hint! It changed the directory but it looks like it is not trying to execute git commands at all..

Comment: any error messages? We can't see your screen, you know?

Comment: No? There is nothing on the screen except 2 lines with dir path.

Comment: what's your current drive? You may want to `cd /d D:\Repositories\myRepo`. You didn't name your batchfile `git.bat`, did you?

Comment: Okay .. adding /d in front of dir path worked .. I don't know why maybe some clarifications would be nice .. now I will research about `schtasks` and will inform you what I've done. Thank you so much about the help so far!

Comment: I've done my research and now I did something but I am not sure if it works as intended and I am afraid I can't check it because of git.            `@echo off

CD /d D:\Repositories\Mobile\mobile
git checkout master
FIND "behind" | git status -uno
IF %errorlevel% EQU 0     
    git up

CD /d D:\Repositories\website\website
git checkout master
FIND "behind" | git status -uno
IF %errorlevel% EQU 0     
    git up

EXIT `

Comment: Please **1**. Do not post larger code snippets in comments: it's totally unreadable; [edit] your question rather. **2**. No not extend topic of your question (tolerable for the present as there is no answer yet). **3**. "_I did something but I am not sure if it works as intended_": and _who_ would know what's intended by _something_?